# Fixed background adjusted to the monitor size

Tags: css, background, background-image

Can you please tell me how to make the background image adjust to the size of the monitor?
Here's what I got:

```
body {
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) #eee fixed no-repeat center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
font: 12px Tahoma, sans-serif;
```

}

Even though I get the vertical scroll bar on one monitor and no scroll bar on the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fixed and centered background

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Works in:

```
Safari 3+
Chrome Whatever+
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)
```

Comment: I use Chrome version 43.0.2357.81 m